# Returning multiple values with a function

Tags: python, function, return

When I print I get 4 codes and 4 dates, but when I use return I only get the first one.

This is a webscraping project with bs4 and requests. Im scraping a website with a regex. I used the containers = soup.find.all(class) method to look for the code blocks with the data I want to extract.

```
def get_codes(containers, pattern):
    for container in containers:
        tweet_bodies = str(container.find('p'))
        shift_codes = re.findall(pattern, tweet_bodies)
        for shift_code in shift_codes:
            str(shift_code)
            return (shift_code)`

def get_date(containers):
    for container in containers:
        tweet_dates = container.find_all('a', class_='tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip')
        for date in tweet_dates:
            if 'title' in date.attrs:
                return (date['title'])`
```

Expected:

```
W9KBJ-95X9T-ZC3KW-BJTJT-5FF3T
CZWJJ-X6XHJ-9CJC5-JTT3J-WZ6WC
KZK3T-K6RSJ-ZWTCK-JTJ3T-T3HJJ
CHCBT-TF6HB-ZC3WC-BT333-KBR3B
13:14 - 28. Okt. 2019
14:30 - 27. Okt. 2019
11:33 - 26. Okt. 2019
15:54 - 25. Okt. 2019`
```

but I only get one date and one code.

Comment: What do you have in `shift_codes` and `date.attrs`

Comment: date.attrs: <a class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" data-conversation-id="1187864936476753921" href="link" title="15:54 - 25. Okt. 2019"></a>

Answer (score 0):

`return` causes the current function to terminate immediately*, so your for loops will only reach the first iteration. If you want to iterate all the way to the end, you can accumulate your values in a list and return that list at the end:

```
def get_codes(containers, pattern):
    results = []
    for container in containers:
        tweet_bodies = str(container.find('p'))
        shift_codes = re.findall(pattern, tweet_bodies)
        for shift_code in shift_codes:
            results.append(str(shift_code))
    return results
```

... Or turn your function into a generator by replacing each `return` with `yield`.

```
def get_codes(containers, pattern):
    for container in containers:
        tweet_bodies = str(container.find('p'))
        shift_codes = re.findall(pattern, tweet_bodies)
        for shift_code in shift_codes:
            yield str(shift_code)
```

(*unless you're inside a `with` block or a `try` block with a `finally`, in which case some cleanup may occur before termination)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if 'title' in date.attrs:
                return (date['title'])
```

Your return is inside an if statement.
This means that your function can return dates but sometimes can return a None.

You need to check why the if statement is False.

In addition, make sure your function always explicitly returns what you meant.